How to cancel a running job and retrieve partial results in IBM Watson Machine Learning with CPLEX?
I am deploying a decision optimization model using IBM Watson Machine Learning (WML) with CPLEX. I need to be able to stop the model execution and retrieve the current solution. I would also like to know if it is possible to get the solution from the .xml and the logs from the .txt every time I call client.deployments.get_job_details(job_uid) and not just at the end. Here is the code I am currently using to start and monitor the job:
solve_payload = {
    "solve_parameters": {
        "oaas.logAttachmentName": "log.txt",
        "oaas.logTailEnabled": "true",
        "oaas.resultsFormat": "XML"
    },
    client.deployments.DecisionOptimizationMetaNames.INPUT_DATA: [],
    client.deployments.DecisionOptimizationMetaNames.OUTPUT_DATA: [{"id": ".*\\.xml"}, {"id": "log.txt"}],
}

job_details = client.deployments.create_job(deployment_uid, solve_payload)
job_uid = client.deployments.get_job_uid(job_details)

while job_details["entity"]["decision_optimization"]["status"]["state"] not in ["completed", "failed", "canceled"]:
    time.sleep(1)
    job_details = client.deployments.get_job_details(job_uid)
    
    state = job_details["entity"]["decision_optimization"]["status"]["state"]
    if state == "queued":
        self.generate_partial_result("Queued Cloud", None)
    elif state == "running":
        self.generate_partial_result("Optimizing", None)

job_details = client.deployments.get_job_details(job_uid)
output_data = job_details["entity"]["decision_optimization"]["output_data"]


